# ROG Maximus XI Hero (wifi) temperature sensor identification in iCue

Tags: motherboard, documentation, corsair

I set up my ROG Maximus and installed iCue. The dashboard intelligently picked up all the voltage and heat senors from the CPU and other parts but not from the motherboard. It just lists Temp #1...to #11.
[image]

I have been looking through the manual and everything i can find, but I have no idea how to tell what sensor is what. I realize i don't have some probes connected to the board, but some of the sensors are giving variable readings. How do i go about figuring our what this information means?

Here are how some other hardware monitors see my system.
OCCT
[image]
Open Hardware monitor
[image]

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @harrymc windows 10 pro

Comment: Are you using the latest iCue version? In Dashboard have you added all sensors under "System Info"? I'm getting in Dashboard very nicely itemized list with sensors and fans, not at all like your screenshot. iCue is known to have problems with some motherboard sensors.

Comment: @harrymc I am using  3.30.97 which is latest according to iCue. I am not sure what you mean about system info. On the dashboard I see other stuff itemized correctly, just the motherboard is like that. I do not see any settings for my motherboard. I expect the ASUS motherboard to work well as they are a Corsair partner

Answer (score 0):

Near the iCue Dashboard tab there is a '+'. Clicking it shows a "System info" item,
and clicking that shows all the classes of items.
Ensure that all items are selected, and especially the motherboard.

On my computer, selecting the motherboard did not help.
I have exactly the same problem with iCue as you, where it cannot find
any of my motherboard sensors.

The website page
[CORSAIR iCUE - Frequently Asked Questions](https://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=176101)
only says this:

> iCUE is our newest software that connects all your **CORSAIR iCUE compatible products**

That same webpage links to the
[iCUE compatibility page](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/CORSAIR-iCUE/c/Cor_Products_iCue_Compatibility?q=%3Afeatured&text=&pageSize=12#rotatingText)
where you may select compatible products by socket type.

As the
[ROG MAXIMUS X HERO](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-X-HERO/)
uses the LGA1151 socket, clicking the "Intel 115x" selection shows only one compatible
device : Hydro X Series XC7 RGB CPU Water Block (115X/AM4),
which has nothing to do with your motherboard.

My conclusion is that iCue is a very limited tool.
As you have found better tools, only use iCue for tasks for which
it is better suited.

Comment: @Andrey: Any comment?

Comment: This does not resolve my problem, and does not explain what it is that iCue is seeing from the hardware. Clearly it can see hardware outside that list. For instance it knows about my CPU, and GPU cores.. It is seeing some info from the motherboard, it's not just making things up. Maybe dupes, maybe wrong,  but not made up.. The trick, and as stated in the bounty is to figure out what. Clearly there is some comparability issues. Everyone knows that.  I am looking for something useful

Comment: It only sees hardware that works with some hardware protocols. Some it can see because Windows knows about, but not query, because it doesn't support the required hardware protocols. There is no solution except improving iCue, which only its developers can do.